# setOnMyLocationListener error in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm unable to set myLocationChange listener.
My code is as follows, and i'm trying to setMyLocationChangeListener in OnMapReady method.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);

    }
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in `googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);` refers to `OnMapReadyCallback` (inner class).

If your external class implements `LocationListener` you need to specify it: `googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(YourClass.this);`